# How can i make my code work with 3 sql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a three sql tables :-

1) OR130a -- I almost need to show all the columns,

2) AL095  -- need 1 IRL column from table,

3) thirdtable --need 1 ARTNO column from table

What I tried till now

```
SELECT c.* , p.IRL 
FROM OR130a c 
     LEFT JOIN AL095 p ON c.artno=p.artno 
ORDER BY HFB;
```

I don't know how to add another join to my query with the third table. I had many try playing with the codes but nothing.

I also have an ARTNO column in the third table. 
And another thing is. The tables are so big and I am not sure, but i would like to get all the records from my main table even if in the additional tables there is no such a row to fetch.

Hope somebody can help me out. Thank you.
Z.

Comment: Just add another `JOIN` after the `ON` clause of your first one.  I don't know anything about your structure or desired results to tell you what to write.

Comment: Where does this `HFB` column comes from?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT c.* , p.IRL, t.ARTNO
FROM OR130a c
     LEFT JOIN AL095 p ON c.artno = p.artno
     LEFT JOIN ThirdTable t ON c.artno = t.artno
ORDER BY HFB
```